# Move daily backup directories (made by rsync) to another directory in the same partition

Tags: rsync, hard-link, move

I have a daily rsync script backing up my data on an external hard drive at `/mnt/X` (root of hard drive). I am using `--link-dest` to use hard links and avoid duplicating data. I need to move all my daily backups from `/mnt/X` to `/mnt/X/backups` without loosing the hard links. Later I will need to change the script to backup in the new dest directory which is `/mnt/X/backups` and look for previous day backup in the same directory.

How would you suggest me to do the move?

Comment: Look at `rsnapshot` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. Simply,

```
mv /mnt/X/* to /mnt/X/backups/
```

(You will get an error about not being able to move `backups` to itself).

A hard link is basically an inode number. Files that are hard-linked have the same inode number. However you move them around within the same file-system, the inode number does not change. So there is no special action needed.

Try it for yourself with some simple files in `/tmp` first:

```
/tmp $ mkdir aa
/tmp $ touch aa/f
/tmp $ ln aa/f aa/g
/tmp $ mkdir aa/new
/tmp $ mv aa/* aa/new
mv: cannot move 'aa/new' to a subdirectory of itself, 'aa/new/new'
/tmp $ ls -il aa/new/
13185910 -rw-r--r-- 2  0 Apr 11 13:32 f
13185910 -rw-r--r-- 2  0 Apr 11 13:32 g
```